# Selecting UITableVewCell with MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell with a mapView on the right:

[image: TableView]

User interaction for the map is disabled. When I tap on the map, the cell highlights as if it is being selected but the segue is not triggered. If I hold my finger on the map for three seconds, then the selection segue is triggered.  Why this behavior?  Is there a way to select the cell without this long press?

Here is my segue code-

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRouteDetail"]){
    RouteDetailTableTableViewController *routeDetailViewController=(RouteDetailTableTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];
    routeDetailViewController.selectedItemID =
    [[self.frc objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]] objectID];
```

The segue is called when I touch the left side of the cell (without the mapview) but requires a three second press over the map.

Here is the storyboard segue-
[image]

Comment: you should add some code. If a segue is attached to each static cell then the methods shouldn't really matter. But you have not specified any of that. What code are you using if any that sends data from the table view cell to another view.

Comment: This is a dynamic table, not static. The segue is connected to the prototype cell in the storyboard.

Comment: Have you find the solution to your problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few things and have a few suggestions.

1. Can I ask why you have 3 segues to the same view? That may have something to do with it as it is trying to navigate which segue is the one required as there are multiple connections to the same cell by the image you've attached.
2. Have you tried removing all segues and then reconnecting just one at a time and testing whether it works each time?
3. I also see that the segue connected and highlighted is called `showRouteDetail` yet your `prepareForSegue` code has `showTourDetail`. Change that to suit the code also.

My suggestion would be have a separate segue and view for `New Route`. This will help with not only saving data cleanly but displaying existing data in it's own view. I see often on `Stackoverflow` people who are double saving the same data, or saving it two times and one comes up blank when they only mean to save once. Also, are you sure your segue is connected to the cell and not the UIImage or labels?

Finally replace some code with this:

```
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

TourDetailTableViewController * tourDetailViewController= segue.destinationViewController;

//assuming you are using fetchedResultsController method to load your data in table view
SkiTour *selectedTour = (SkiTour*) [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

tourDetailViewController.tourID =selectedTour.objectID;
```

These are just some simple checks and changes.

**UPDATE BASED ON NEW DETAILS**

If you have a button overlapping the `MapView` it would be better to programmatically swap views than to have a segue connected. To do this add this code to the correlating Button:

```
- (IBAction) viewMapButton: (UIButton *)sender{

    //create access to the next view
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewMap"];

    //this will perform a push segue so that navigation bar still exists and can respond
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated:YES];  

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong segue code (now fixed).  The three segues are one for the New Route button on top of the table, one for a temporary button over the map to trigger a segue and the one I am trying to get to work.  Even when I remove these segues, I get the same result.  It seems that a UILabel transfers the touch to the cell but MapView does not?

Comment: @David Don't connect to a button within a Reusable TableView Cell this is common reason for issues. Connect a segue directly to the cell or Use code within the IBaction to swap views. I will update my answer to show how. Is there any reason why you are connecting to the map and not the cell though? Also connecting a segue to a label does not work (in my experience) because a label is static, it does not handle any actions.

Comment: I was originally connecting the segue to the cell, but was unable to trigger when touching over the map.  The button is a hack in order to make that part of the cell responsive. It is a little tricky to obtain the selected cell from the uibutton since the cell is not actually selected, but this may be the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: Exactly my sentiment. Connect the Segue to the prototype cell. Much easier to get accurate details. Are you trying to view just a map or all the details related to that cell, or both but in seperate views?

Comment: I need to pass on the core data object from the selected cell to the next view.

Comment: So you need to connect the segue to the cell and use prepareForSegue to do it :-) Easy now I know that. Use the code I initially pasted in the prepareForSegue code and you are all set providing you have the segue connected to the cell and not the map or label

Comment: Yes, that is how I had it set up.  The problem is that when I touch the right side of the cell (over the map) it is not selected and the segue is not triggered.

Comment: Yeh I get that. Could you put a UIImageView on top of it and set it to clear so that the Map is totally inaccessible to touch (despite being disabled). On a side note I am excited for you about your project, it sounds pretty neat based on short conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66629/discussion-between-david-and-the-rooster).